# How to immediately show scroll bar in the JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I added `JScrollPane` to my `JPanel` but I wanted to make scroll bar visible at the start of the program not only when the text is going out of the screen is that possible?

```
jpMiddle = new JPanel();
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20,43);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta); 

    jpMiddle.add(sp);
```

Comment: JScrollPane has other constructors you can use, or properties you can set. Check the [JScrollPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html). ;)

Comment: check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b6d708bf-da6a-4f77-afa2-eccee177a316

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta, 
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

That's for the scrollbars to be active always, you can substitute the ALWAYS for AS_NEEDED to ensure they appear only when the contents of ths scrollpane overflows.

The API exists for one reason, though...